# Team Fortress 2 Sound Stops Working After Using Microphone

Tags: 14.04, sound, games, steam, microphone

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64. When I am playing Team Fortress 2 through Steam, everything is fine until I start using my microphone. After about 20-30 minutes or so, all audio stops working. As far as I can tell in this state, the microphone still works, but I can't confirm due to lack of audio.

Update: I also have setup Counter-Strike: Global Offensive through PlayOnLinux/Wine, and the sound also stops working in this game, generally when I move from one server to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try minimizing and going to the sound settings from the upper right volume control, then switch from your preferred audio device to some other, and then back.

This works for me when I oddly lose sound. It has something to do with switching programs I think.

Comment: This does not work for me. A new symptom is that playing YouTube videos while testing for sound plays at an uneven pace (fast, then slow, then fast then slow...).